# Get data pivot table VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have generated a pivot table with the following code.

```
Sub TCD()

Dim last_row As Integer
last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim My_range As Range
 Set My_range = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(last_row, 2))


Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim StartPvt As String
Dim pf_Name As String


'Create a new worksheet
  Set sht = Sheets.Add
  sht.Name = "TCD"
'Where do you want Pivot Table to start?
  StartPvt = "TCD" & "!" & sht.Range("A1").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'Create Pivot Cache from Source Data
  Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=My_range)

'Create Pivot table from Pivot Cache
  Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable( _
    TableDestination:=StartPvt, _
    TableName:="PivotTable1")

 pvt.PivotFields("Type_c").Orientation = xlRowField
 pf_Name = "Max iteration par type"

pvt.AddDataField pvt.PivotFields("Nb_Iteration"), pf_Name, xlMax
```

'Part of code that does nothing

```
 Dim dbl As Double
    dbl = pvt.GetData(Name:="CP")

    End Sub
```

The pivot table looks like this

[image]

How can I retrieve the number of each row element ? I have tried using get data (last two lines of code) and getpivotdata. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
dbl = pvt.GetData("'Max iteration par type' CP")
```